# Can I run an arbitrary Oracle SQL script through ODP.NET?

Tags: oracle, odp.net

Is there a way to run an arbitrary sql script through ODP.NET?  I'd like to do something like this:

```
SomeOracleObject.RunFile("myfile.sql");
```

In other words, I want to obviate the need for sqlplus.exe.

Comment: Normally, a SQL script in Oracle contains SQL and PL/SQL as well as SQL*Plus commands.  Do you need to support scripts that include SQL*Plus commands (SPOOL, BREAK, COLUMN, etc.)?  Or do you just want to run a file that contains SQL and PL/SQL commands?

Comment: Just SQL and PL/SQL commands.  These scripts are expressly written by us for this .NET code to run.

Comment: So I guess that's not really arbitrary... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for a similar solution to the problem.  I [posted on the Oracle forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4139676) for ODP.NET but it appears no one from Oracle actually participates in the forums. The closest thing I have seen to this is DevArt's dotConnect for Oracle's [OracleScript class](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleScript.html).  Ideally I want the same functionality I have inside the SQL Server Management Objects, but for Oracle.  If I had my choice, I would move back to SQL Server because of things like this - but it's not my choice to make. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet of code I use to do exactly what you're asking.

```
    using (OracleConnection conn = CreateConnection(confConnString))
    {
        try
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = scriptFileContents;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: This doesn't work - when I try to do that, I get an ORA-00911 error as it doesn't like the ; at the end of SQL statements

Comment: Try wrapping each script file's contents in BEGIN  /  END;